# Cannot find a correct control for this JavaFX screen

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I cannot get the proper control from the UI controls available in JavaFX. I'm using Scene Builder by Gluon. I want to design my screen similar to the below images. I need a control similar to the sidebar used in many Android apps, e.g Gmail for Android. In bitbucket, the control can be in two states collapsed and expanded. They happen by clicking on an arrow in the vertical center of the bar. Is there a similar control in JavaFX that can be configured in the same way?

[sidebar collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNOeh.png)

[sidebar expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXEvy.png)

Comment: There's nothing built in to JavaFX for this. You would have to write the code yourself.

Comment: Yeah @James_D, but there must be at least a basic control. I get it that I'll need to write custom actions with animations but I need to choose that primary control, correctly!

Comment: No, there's no "control". You just put stuff into whatever container is most convenient, and rearrange the layout when it's expanded/collapsed.

Comment: There are many ways to do so, and since there is no built-in way the question is probably too broad. My best advice would be to start implementing one yourself, and if you come up with concrete problems ("I can't seem to make X do Y. I tried A, B and C but encountered this error/problem...") - come back and ask....

Comment: @sillyfly, just needed a heads up for such task. Nevertheless, I'm on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually done this recently. It's not all that hard, really, just takes time to put all of the pieces together.  I've set up an [example app in GitHub](https://github.com/nevisnor/left-menu-sandbox).

[image]

[image]

Comment: your example works great. It provides me with the basic structure. I'll apply few more tweaks.